# React Native 0.64.2/Xcode 12.5/13 beta: Multiple commands produce with New Build System (Default)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

After adding a few fonts (react-native-vector-icons 8.1.0) to app RN 0.64.2/xcode 13 beta, compiling with `New Build System (Default)` keeps popping up error of `Multiple commands produce...`. Here is one of them:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/macair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xyz_app4-dhfprmcbidzrywawmsdfnmznbour/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xyz_app4.app/AntDesign.ttf':
1) Target 'xyz_app4' (project 'xyz_app4') has copy command from '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app4/ios/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to '/Users/macair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xyz_app4-dhfprmcbidzrywawmsdfnmznbour/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xyz_app4.app/AntDesign.ttf'
2) Target 'xyz_app4' (project 'xyz_app4') has copy command from '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app4/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to '/Users/macair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xyz_app4-dhfprmcbidzrywawmsdfnmznbour/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xyz_app4.app/AntDesign.ttf'
3) That command depends on command in Target 'xyz_app4' (project 'xyz_app4'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

If using `Legacy Build System` (deprecated), then those error disappeared. Downgrading the Xcode version was not helping. There is only one device target selected for build which is `iPhone`. How to fix this for `New Build System`?

Answer (score 2):

After deleting all entries related to `react-native-vector-icons` under `Copy bundle resources` of `Build phases` for the project, then compiling succeeds.